# Jquery .live() event not working on Firefox and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, jquery

I have live events with submit and click:

```
<form class='myform'>
    <input type='text' name='fruit'>
</form>
<a href='#' class='formSubmit'>Submit</a>
```

I have jquery that calls the form to submit via Enter or clicking the  tag

```
$('a.formSubmit').live('click', function(){
    $('form.myform').submit();

    return false;
});

$('form.myform').live('submit', function(){
    //conditional statements here
});
```

So the problem is, my jquery scripts works fine on all browsers except IE and FireFox. It seems that .live() method is the cause. because when i remove live() method and do it just click() method it will work. Now i need to do it on live() method cause i will be having functionality with newly appended elements and forms. Is there any way to make it work on Firefox and IE?

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery `.live()` is deprecated in version 1.7.+. Use `.on()` instead.

Comment: What version(s) of FF and IE are you trying? Also, what version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: @j08691 i didnt get any errors, its just simply wont work

Comment: @MBJ latest version of FF and IE9. Jquery 1.7

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('#not_dynamically_generated_parent').on('click','a.formSubmit', function(){
    $('form.myform').submit();

    return false;
});

$('#not_dynamically_generated_parent').on('submit','form.myform', function(){
    //conditional statements here
});
```

Comment: For `$('#not_dynamically_generated_parent')` I like to use `$(document)`. It makes is easy to chain multiple events.

Comment: @MBJ .. depends on the use. I prefer some strict parent element to preserve some JS processing work while my brutal sliders run all over the page ;)

Comment: "depends on the use" - I agree 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Ha, i found the solution. My suspect was wrong at all. jquery live() method works fine, the only thing that made the script not working is this `event.preventDefault();` if you have something like that inside the event method, it wont work on firefox and ie... thanks for contributing guys.

Comment: I have to strongly disagree with your statement "...if you have..." `.preventDefault();` "...inside the event method, it wont work on firefox and ie...". I use it all the time; jQuery is made to be cross-browser.